# How to get the arn of a newly created aws_cloudformation_stack terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this resource being created by terraform. How can I reference the arn in the next resource creation?

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "datadog_forwarder" {
  name         = "datadog-forwarder"
  capabilities = ["CAPABILITY_IAM", "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]
  parameters = {
    DdApiKeySecretArn = "secret_arn",
    DdSite            = "datadoghq.com",
    FunctionName      = "datadog-forwarder"
    DdTags            = "env:dev"
  }
  template_url = "https://datadog-cloudformation-template.s3.amazonaws.com/aws/forwarder/latest.yaml"
}
```

I need it referenced here:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "datadog_log_subscription_navblue-dd-agent" {
  name            = "datadog_log_subscription_filter"
  log_group_name  = "/"
  destination_arn = ARN_GOES_HERE
  filter_pattern  = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data "aws_cloudformation_stack" "datadog-cf-arn" {
  name = "datadog-forwarder"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "datadog_log_subscription_navblue-dd-agent" {
  name            = "datadog_log_subscription_filter"
  log_group_name  = "/"
  destination_arn = data.aws_cloudformation_stack.datadog-cf-arn.id
  filter_pattern  = ""
}
```

This is how you can use data to fetch CloudFormation arn. Hope this will help you to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **data source** [aws_cloudformation_stack](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudformation_stack) to query the datadog stack that you just created. If you do that, you will find ARN in the [output](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudformation_stack#outputs) argument of the data source.